# AWS EC2/Spot permissions API

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm a newbie at AWS, and what I'm trying to do seems simple, however I'm stumped after an afternoon of looking at the documentation.

I have inherited some code (javascript/node), that sets up some Ec2 instances. The code all works fine if you have the right permissions setup on your account. However it fails if you sign into an account that doesn't have all of the IAM permissions setup.

I've got my list of permissions that the script requires, and I'd like to find a way to query AWS that the current AccessKey/Secret combo has permission X. And I'm not finding a way to do that in the docs.

Closest I've come is finding a command line 'aws iam list-roles' that lists some permissions but not all of them that the account as setup.

Anyone got a good pointer or reference to helping me find what AWS permissions an account has?

Comment: Can't you just login to the AWS Management Console and view the Users and their permissions there? It's easier than doing CLI calls. Or did you need this to be automated?

Comment: I was looking for how to automate it. 
Basically I want to run a check to see if you have the permissions, before the script kicks off and tries to setup instances.

Answer (score 0):

- **Access Keys** belong to an IAM User
- An **IAM User** can have directly-attached **inline policies** that can be viewed via [list-attached-user-policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-user-policies.html)
- An **IAM User** can have **managed policies** attached to them, that can be viewd via [list-user-policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-user-policies.html)
- An **IAM User** can belong to **Groups** that can be viewed via [list-groups-for-user](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-groups-for-user.html)
- An **IAM Group** can have directly **inline policies** that can be listed via [list-group-policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-group-policies.html)
- An **IAM Group** can have **managed policies** attached to them, that can be viewed via [list-attached-group-policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-attached-group-policies.html)
- The **contents of policies** can be obtained via [get-policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-policy.html), [get-user-policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user-policy.html) and [get-group-policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-group-policy.html)

However, the returned policy is written in JSON and would be a challenge to parse.

It might be easier for you to **create a managed policy** with the permissions you want them to have, and then attach the policy to those users. That way, you'll know they have the right permissions rather than having to check each user.

By the way, I've linked to the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) API calls, but there are equivalent calls in the SDK for each other programming language.